# D3 JS select multiple countries for highlighting issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Basically I'm rendering a map of Europe, it is taking all the countries and giving them a colour as far as I can understand from this line of code
`.attr("fill", "#348C31") // Color Of Country`

when I click a country I can highlight it by using the onclick attrib and the "this" statement like so `d3.select(this).style("fill", '#03a5fd');`
how would I be able to select multiple countries in this d3.select function to change there color? Any help would be appreciated as I'm confused as to how it can be done.

```
// Create an Svg variable
    const svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width")

    // Map and projection
    const projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
        .scale(width / 1.9) // Lower the num closer the zoom
        .translate([200, 550])  // (Horizontal, Vertical)

    // Load external data from geographic api and use data to project path info from map.
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson").then(function (data) {
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(data.features)
            .join("path")
            .style("stroke", "white")// Border Lines
            .attr("fill", "#348C31") // Color Of Country
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight certain countries based on data, by using a function to set the attribute/style of the element. Since there is no data in the geo-json except the name of the country, the snippet below adds an array `selectableCountries` that contains some countries to be highlighted. One way of doing this could be to conditionally add a class

```
selection.classed("selectable", d => selectableCountries.includes(d.properties.name))
```

Alternatively, one can filter the desired elements using the `selection.filter` method of `d3-selection`.

```
selection.filter(d => selectableCountries.includes(d.properties.name))
  .classed("selectable", true)
```

That way, one can also add event listeners to a subset of the selection

```
selection.filter(d => selectableCountries.includes(d.properties.name))
  .classed("selectable", true)
  .on("click", function(event, datum) {})
```

The `datum` of the clicked element is passed as a second argument to the `click` event handler. In the snippet below this is used to highlight the countries with the same first character in the `click` event handler.

```js
// The svg
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

// Map and projection
const projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
  .scale(width / 1.3 / Math.PI)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
const geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

// Countries that can be clicked on
const selectableCountries = ["USA", "Brazil", "India", "France", "Algeria"];

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson")
  .then(function(data) {
    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data.features)
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", geoPath)
      .filter(d => selectableCountries.includes(d.properties.name))
      .classed("selectable", true)
      .on("click", function(event, datum) {
        d3.selectAll("path.highlighted").classed("highlighted", false);
        d3.select(this).classed("highlighted", true);
        const startCharacter = datum.properties.name[0];
        svg.selectAll("path")
          .filter(d => d.properties.name[0] === startCharacter)
          .classed("highlighted", true);
      });
  });
```

```css
.country {
  fill: lightgrey;
  stroke: white;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.selectable {
  fill: teal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlighted {
  fill: dimgrey;
}

.selectable.highlighted {
  fill: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="selected">
  No country selected.
</h1>
<svg width="800" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi, what I'm doing is only showing certain countries which my API supports within Europe. I want to make it so that you can only click the EU countries that I input.

Comment: I edited the post including your additional requirements.